# Read PGM files in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, face-detection, pgm

I want to read pgm files for glasses detection in Machine Learning
Right now I Import pgm_reader

```
from pgm_reader import Reader
```

then I Import os  and defiend a Series for save Images into and I tried to read files like this

```
import os
reader = Reader()
Faces = pd.Series()
files_name = os.listdir('Faces/')
for file_name in files_name:
    file_name = 'Faces/' + file_name
    Faces.add(reader.read_pgm(file_name))
Faces
```

But I had this Error

```
 not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question this way:

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image 
Faces = []
files_name = os.listdir('Faces/')
for file_name in files_name:
    file_name = 'Faces/' + file_name
    face = np.array(Image.open(file_name)) 
    Faces.append(face)
```